# Is it safe to assume that the URL of a public SQS queue can be kept secret?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-sqs, long-polling

I'm creating an online food ordering system, with real-time display of new orders in the browser.

I'm tempted to use the [SQS long polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html) feature for this:

- create one SQS queue per restaurant
- give each queue a pseudo-random, secret name
- make it public, so that the browser can read and delete from the queue directly

Is it safe to assume that the SQS URL made up of the pseudo-random secret name cannot be guessed, given that the queue URL will only ever appear in the given restaurant's admin area?

Bonus question: **Are there better alternatives?** I would especially consider an alternative that would allow me to create a single queue for all restaurants, and use websockets instead of long polling.

Comment: Making SQS queue public is not recommended. Usually you would proxy through api gateway. Have you considered that?

Comment: Never a good idea! You could have the browser authenticate via AWS Cognito, and then make authenticated calls to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against “security through obscurity”. Nowadays it is very easy to enumerate millions of possible URLs in seconds with automated scripts.

I’m not sure about your use case, but [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) is a very versatile service that might provide a solution for you.

Comment: How is a secret URL with enough entropy different from a strong username/password combination? AFAIK username/password is not considered « security through obscurity »? A secret URL is also used by GitHub gists, for example.

Comment: Just one example why it’s different: You can take measures against someone brute-forcing username/password combos (as long as you didn’t leak your hashes). By the nature of the internet and how DNS works you can’t do anything against an attacker enumerating subdomains. Having that said, username/password combos aren’t considered very secure either and there are many editors trying to move to stronger and more secure mechanisms, like temporary access keys, MFA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that I would not make your queue public.  I see two possible solutions:

1. A proxy of some sort in front of your queue.  As suggested you'll want your users to login some where.  With that they can be given a short lived key (such as a JWT) that could be verified by, for example, API Gateway.  API Gateway would sit in front of your Lambda.  API Gateway gives you the potential to do things like IP pass/block lists, throttling, and other controls.
2. A non-AWS pub/sub service such as PubNub.  While I can't tell you if they're using websockets or long polling you really don't care - it's their Javascript library.  An advantage is that they have a ton of backend libraries too that you could integrate with.  I am not associated with PubNub but have used them in the past.